# Customising wordpress search and using $_GET["s"]

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, search

My theme's `search.php` currently has a few "IF" statements to deal with the different types of search that my website uses.

I have a site-wide search, a species (custom post type) specific search and an advanced species search.

For the "species" search, I've simply added an input akin to `<input type="hidden" name="type" value="species" />`. This search uses a single input field to search my species custom post type. Users would likely opt to use this search if they were looking for the common or scientific name of a fish.

For the "advanced species" search, I'm using 12 different inputs (pH, size, temp, etc). I'm building an $args array for `meta_query` in the `WP_Query` class with this data, i.e:

`array(
  'key' => 'genus',
  'value' => $_GET["genus"]
)`

As a result however, the generic `<input name="s">` isn't being used, and as such, the form action isn't working (just loads the index page without searching).

Is there a better way of doing this? I could obviously just send "s" as a hidden input with a generic value, but that's a cheap and ugly way of going about things.

Maybe this should be a page separate to our search page? I'd prefer to do it in `search.php` though or there will be some redundant copying of HTML structure etc for no real reason.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you're worried about C+Ping HTML structure, why not use [template parts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) to render the results? That way you can separate out the explicit metaquery logic into its own, more relevant template.

Comment: This is something I'd never struck on and might be quite handy. Thanks Simon, I'll investigate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking @Simon Scarfe 's advice using `get_template_part`.

Just in case anyone ever needs it, this page (a work in progress) creates an advanced search form, then builds a WP_Query to search a custom post type:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST["act"]) && $_POST["act"] == "s") : ?>

<?php
    $meta_query = array('relation' => 'AND');

    if (!empty($_POST["s_genus"])) {
        $genus = array(
            'key' => 'genus',
            'value' => $_POST["s_genus"],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );
        $meta_query[] = $genus;
    }

    if (!empty($_POST["s_species"])) {
        $species = array(
            'key' => 'species',
            'value' => $_POST["s_species"],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );
        $meta_query[] = $species;
    }

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'species',
        'meta_query' => $meta_query
    );

    get_template_part('searchresults');
?>

<?php else : ?>

    <div id="content">
        <h2>ADVANCED<span class="lblue">SEARCH</span></h2>

        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="act" value="s" />
            <fieldset id="taxonomy" style="margin-right: 15px;">
                <legend>Taxonomy</legend>
                <label for="genus">Genus</label>
                    <input class="full" type="text" name="s_genus" />
                <br />
                <label for="species">Species</label>
                    <input class="full" type="text" name="s_species" />
                <br />
                <label for="family">Family</label>
                    <input class="full" type="text" name="s_family" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then, in `searchresults.php` I have this code, which is just a couple of lines then a single change to a standard page template:

```
<?php global $args; ?>

<?php $query = new WP_Query ( $args ); ?>

<?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
    <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

    <p class="info">Search results for <em>&#8216;<?php echo $s ?>&#8217;</em></p>

    </div>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

            <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> &mdash; <?php the_time('h:i a') ?> <?php edit_post_link('Edit','<strong> |</strong> ',''); ?> </small>

            <div class="entry">
                <?php the_content('Continue reading &raquo;'); ?>
            </div>

            <p class="info"><?php comments_popup_link('Comment &raquo;', '1 comment &raquo;', '% comments &raquo;'); ?> <strong>|</strong> <?php the_category(', ') ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <p align="center"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Entries') ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php previous_posts_link('Next Entries &raquo;') ?></p><?php else : ?>

    <h2>Not Found</h2>

    <p>Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like  as you suggest why is that cheap and ugly? it saves you from having to rebuild a whole search mechanism, and dealing with the template hierarchy. and as you say it's sharing html on the search page. Go for it!

Comment: Yeah of course you're right, maybe it's just a bit of an OCD thing - I thoroughly dislike the idea of "cheating" WordPress behaviour :) If all else fails, maybe this is the answer!